# Spring: How to replace the Environment bean created in Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I am looking to replace the Environment bean used by Spring with my own implementation. Is this bad-practice, and if not, how can I do this cleanly? Currently I have created a bean that implements the Environment interface and uses the existing Environment bean, but this means all the configuration code needing the Environment bean must now use my custom Environment bean. I would think it would be cleaner to replace Springs Environment bean with my own, then no configuration needing it would need to change. Currently the only way I can think to do this would be to either create my own ApplicationContext thus setting the environment to my own, or to have something be ApplicationContextAware and set the environment there. Both of these seem to be a bit hokey to me.

Constraints:

- I am using the latest version of Spring3.
- I am using Java based configuration; not XML

Thank you.

**Edit: Background**

I suppose I should explain why I want to do this in case my thinking is flawed. I was avoid this in order to avoid the nonconstructive "why would you want to do that?" responses.

The Spring Environment bean, when looking for property values, uses a set of property sources. A typical stack looks like this (but is not limited to):

- JNDI
- System Properties (set via -Dmyprop=foo)
- Environment Variables
- ...

For security reason, it is necessary to encrypt some of these properties (e.g. database passwords). The go to solution is to use Jasypt for property encryption. However, the Spring/Jasypt only provide a means of inserting a new property source into the environment. So:

- Property file with potentially encrypted values
- JNDI
- System Properties (set via -Dmyprop=foo)
- Environment Variables
- ...

However, this is not ideal as this means that properties can only be stored in a single file to be maintained by the operations group or that properties would be spread out amongst property files, environment variables, etc. In addition, I feel that properties have the potential of being encrypted regardless of their property source.

So this lead me to thinking that I either need to decrypt the properties in my code wherever I attempt to access them from the environment, or I need to create my own Environment bean that can do this for me.

I'm welcome to hear **constructive** comments and alternatives.

**EDIT: Adding solution based on answer from M. Deinum**

```
public class EnvironmentBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private static final String CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBE_ALGORITHM";
    private static final String CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_PBE_PASSWORD = "PBE_PASSWORD";

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        StandardEnvironment environment = (StandardEnvironment) beanFactory.getBean("environment");

        if (environment != null) {
            StringEncryptor encryptor = this.getEncryptor(environment);

            MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = environment.getPropertySources();

            for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : mutablePropertySources) {
                mutablePropertySources.replace(
                        propertySource.getName(), 
                        new EncryptablePropertySourcePropertySource(propertySource.getName(), propertySource, encryptor));
            }
        }
    }

    private StringEncryptor getEncryptor(Environment environment) {
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

        String algorithm = environment.getProperty(CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_PBE_ALGORITHM);
        if (algorithm != null) {
            encryptor.setAlgorithm(algorithm);
        }

        String password = environment.getProperty(CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_PBE_PASSWORD);
        if (password != null) {
            encryptor.setPassword(password);
        }

        return encryptor;
    }

    private class EncryptablePropertySourcePropertySource extends PropertySource<PropertySource<?>> {

        private StringEncryptor stringEncryptor;

        private TextEncryptor textEncryptor;

        public EncryptablePropertySourcePropertySource(final String name, final PropertySource<?> propertySource, final StringEncryptor encryptor) {
            super(name, propertySource);

            this.stringEncryptor = encryptor;
        }

        public EncryptablePropertySourcePropertySource(final String name, final PropertySource<?> propertySource, final TextEncryptor encryptor) {
            super(name, propertySource);

            this.textEncryptor = encryptor;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getProperty(String name) {
            Object value = this.source.getProperty(name);

            if (value != null && value instanceof String) {
                value = this.decode((String) value);
            }

            return value;
        }

        private String decode(String encodedValue) {
            if (!PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.isEncryptedValue(encodedValue)) {
                return encodedValue;
            }

            if (this.stringEncryptor != null) {
                return PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(encodedValue, this.stringEncryptor);

            }

            if (this.textEncryptor != null) {
                return PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(encodedValue, this.textEncryptor);
            }

            throw new EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException(
                    "Neither a string encryptor nor a text encryptor exist "
                    + "for this instance of EncryptableProperties. This is usually " 
                    + "caused by the instance having been serialized and then "
                    + "de-serialized in a different classloader or virtual machine, " 
                    + "which is an unsupported behaviour (as encryptors cannot be "
                    + "serialized themselves)");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by rolling up your own `Environment` that cannot be accomplished with standard Spring stuff?

Comment: I see `AbstractApplicationContext`'s `setEnvironment()` method is public. So, you can get a hold of the app context with a bean implementing `ApplicationContextAware` and from there you can set your own Environment. Haven't tried it, but I think this would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I was thinking this was an option, however i was concerned about the implications. From Springs own documentation, it states "Sometimes this capability is useful; however, in general you should avoid it, because it couples the code to Spring and does not follow the Inversion of Control style, where collaborators are provided to beans as properties." My question was more around learning best practice.

Comment: I am not sure the `Environment` is the place for encrypting/decrypting stuff, I mean it's not its purpose in my opinion. I was thinking, after I've seen the additional explanation about encrypting, if maybe AOP would be an option. An aspect and a pointcut that should intercept `EnumerablePropertySource.getProperty()` method, for example...

Comment: @loesak I see your point in needing to have encrypted properties no matter the source, but I would disagree that you should have so many sources of configuration in one application. In my mind, properties files are a great solution for configuration that meets the needs of developers in development and testing environments and also SysAdmin people in production environments. With that said I would suggest you extend the other sources of configuration in the spirit of `EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource ` instead of implementing your own Environment

Comment: @geoand normally if we were just a single application deployed in a single environment i would agree with you. However, our application has the need to be deployed as SaaS in any ecosystem or OnPrem. We don't have the luxury of informing the owning installers where they should keep their configuration settings. Also putting properties in one type of store, if not chosen properly lends to the inability to share those properties amongst different applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the Spring/Jasypt only provide a means of inserting a new property source into the environment.

Actually that is where you are wrong, you can replace `PropertySources` as well. See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html) of [`MutablePropertySources`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html). This is also used internally by Spring to first add some dummy `PropertySources` and replace them later.

What you could do is create a `PropertySource` which delegates to another `PropertySource` and decrypts the value on the fly. That way you could replace all `PropertySources` with a one which wraps around the original.

```
MutablePropertySources mps = env.getgetPropertySources();
for (PropertySource ps : env.getgetPropertySources()) {
    EncryptablePropertySource eps = new EncryptablePropertySource(ps.getName(), ps, encryptor);
    mps.replace(ps.getName(), eps);
}
```

You could use the [`EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource`](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt-spring31/1.9.2/org/jasypt/spring31/properties/EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource.html) as a sample, what you basically need to do is replace the `Properties` with `PropertySource`.

It would be easier if [SPR-8928](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8928) would be fixed as that would allow simply for the `EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to be registered and all properties would converted and you wouldn't need these hacks.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid I may have been wrong and was hoping so. I'll look into this and if it the right avenue will mark answer appropriately.

Comment: As i am looking into this, I believe this is the appropriate way to do this until that bug is fixed. What I am not aware of is how to make sure this happens prior to any bean needing the environment?

Comment: thinking BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Comment: this lead me down a better path. I created a BeanFactoryPostProcessor that wrapped each PropertySource of the environment property sources with a custom PropertySource that could decrypt the properties as they are fetched from their original property source.

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution i came up with from the help of this answer.